# How to add a custom suffix to a Big Number with Trendline value

Tags: apache-superset

I would like to add a static string suffix to the Big Number with Trendline chart in Superset. I'm specifically looking to add "hours" to the number. Here is what I've tried so far:

- `,d hours`
- `,d 'hours'`
- `,d + hours`
- `,d = ' hours'`

I do see a *Duration in ms* selection in the Number Format field, but that doesn't seem to have any unit customization.

Alternatively, I'd be okay with the ability to show the Metric label via a checkbox to enable it.

Answer (score 0):

As of Superset 2.0.0, a variable can't have a suffix added.  There is a feature request for this functionality posted on GitHub: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/16610.

For a Big Number chart though, you can approximate this by using the `SUBHEADER` field which accepts arbitrary text and whose size can be controlled.  Example:

[image]